# Getting unwanted output when printing to stderr in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, stderr

My code basically looks like this, after taking out only the relevant parts for this:

```
import sys
print("error", "", "\n", sys.stderr, False)
```

The output is:

```
 error
  <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> False
```

Why am I getting that second line and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the second line because [`print` prints the list of things you give it in sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). So you're printing `error`, then nothing, then a newline, then `sys.stderr` - which has it's own string representation which is `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>`, and then `False`.

From the REPL:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print("a", "b", "c")
a b c
>>> print(sys.stderr)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Given that, you should clarify what you *expected* the output to be. Presumably you're trying to print to `stderr`, in which case you need to make use of 'named parameters':

```
>>> print("a", "b", "c", sep=' +++ ', end='\n', file=sys.stderr, flush=False)
a +++ b +++ c
```

Note that because the signature for `print` includes as it's first parameter `*objects`, it will assume everything handed to it is something it is printing. You *must* name the `sep`, `end`, `file` and `flush` parameters if you want to set them.